# Laravel 6 Validation Bug?

Tags: laravel

I have a problem about my Laravel project.

```php
$request->validate(
[
    'blogs_file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
    'blogs_title' => 'required|unique:App\Blogs,blogs_title',
    'blogs_content' => 'required',
]);
```

I made a limit to blogs_file. It should only allowed jpg,png,jpeg and max 2 MB.

But when i try to put a mp4 file, it pass. What is the problem there?

I have already added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form on blade page.

If i want to put an mp4 file or zip lower than 2 MB the validation works fine. But if i upload any kind of data upper than 2 MB; it passes. Actually, when i check to my db; blogs_file coming NULL on that way, but it returns with  success message to user.

UPDATE:

my create.blade.php file;

```html
<div class="box-body">
    <form action="{{route('blogs.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Resim Seç</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" required name="blogs_file" type="file">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Başlık</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" required type="text" placeholder="Blog Başlığı..." name="blogs_title">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Sayfa Linki</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Sayfa linki girebilirsiniz(isteğe bağlı)"
                           name="blogs_slug" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>İçerik</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="editor1" name="blogs_content"
                              required></textarea>
                </div>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Durum</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <select name="blogs_status" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Aktif</option>
                        <option value="0">Pasif</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div align="right" class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ekle</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

route:

```
Route::resource('blogs','BlogController');
```

BlogController:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (strlen($request->blogs_slug)>3)
    {
        $slug=Str::slug($request->blogs_slug);
    } else {
        $slug=Str::slug($request->blogs_title);
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('blogs_file'))
    {
        $request->validate(
        [
            'blogs_file' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
            'blogs_title' => 'required|unique:App\Blogs,blogs_title',
            'blogs_content' => 'required',
        ]);

        $file_name=uniqid().".".$request->blogs_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->blogs_file->move(public_path('images/blogs'),$file_name);
        $request->blogs_file=$file_name;
    }
    $blog= new Blogs;
    $blog->blogs_file=$request->blogs_file;
    $blog->blogs_title=$request->blogs_title;
    $blog->blogs_slug=$slug;
    $blog->blogs_content=$request->blogs_content;
    $blog->blogs_status=$request->blogs_status;
    $blog->uniqid=uniqid();
    $blog->save();
    if ($blog)
    {
        return redirect(route('blogs.index'))->with('success','İşlem Başarılı!');
    } else {

        return back()->with('error','İşlem Başarısız!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But your validation says you don't accept mp4 files. So that should fail right? Could you maybe add your form to the question?

Comment: Show your form, or if you're submitting through AJAX, the `$.post` (or equivalent) JS method you're using.

Comment: @Ruub, But if i upload any mp4 or rar files larger than 2 MB, it accepts. It should return with error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st. You have missed `file` rule.

2nd. You may use either `image` rule (that validates a file to be jpeg, png, bmp, gif, svg, or webp) or use `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png`:

So your validation would be either:

```php
'blogs_file' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
```

Or:

```php
'blogs_file' => 'required|file|image|max:2048',
```

3rd. You've put your validation `$request->validate` inside an `if`, it's wrong and makes the problem! You may [conditionally adding rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) or use [after validation hook](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#after-validation-hook) for more complex validations instead.

Comment: I updated like you said: 'blogs_file' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048',
But the problem still continue. I'm testing with mp4 file 10 MB. It shouldn't accept. :(

Comment: @BoraN update your questions and post your form and/or js code you use to submit the request please.

Comment: @BoraN how you're checking your validation errors? you are not displaying any error on your blade, check this: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: ,To use all page, i just create a session to my layout blade page. It work for all of my moduls. if(session()->has('success'))
    <script type="text/javascript">alertify.success('{{session('success')}}')</script>
endif
if(session()->has('error'))
    <script type="text/javascript">alertify.error('{{session('error')}}')</script>
endif

Comment: P.S: I remove @ sign on if statements. It doesn't allow me to write here. It has on the code.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I remove if hasfile part and it works right now! I should keep not that i never use validate inside if segment i guess?

Comment: @BoraN sure, never put validation inside an if, instead you may use conditional validation if you needed more complex validations in the future: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules meanwhile, don't forget to accept this as an answer please ;)